# kernel hangs up at boot indefinitely

Tags: linux, debugging, linux-kernel, kernel

I have configured the kernel with `linux slob allocator` to implement best fit algorithm. I build the and installed the kernel image so that I can boot from it next time. Now when I try to boot this kernel it hangs indefinitely, the cursor just does not even blink. The following messages are printed before the cursor hangs up:

```
[0.000325] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[0.001461] Security Framework initialized
[0.002108] AppArmor: AppArmor initialized
```

After this message the cursor hangs up indefinitely. I would like to know some kernel debugging tricks that would help me to navigate through the problem or some good read.
I have also configured `kdb` but do not know how to use it in such a condition. Any help is appriciated!!

Additional details:

I have modified the `slob_page_alloc` function to implement `best-fit` algorithm which is in turn called by `slob_alloc` function. I am using `v3.6.2`

Comment: Have you verified that the best-fit algorithm works correctly as a standalone piece of code? (Automated testing could be your friend in this case.)

Comment: @MarkLeightonFisher No. I have not but I am quite sure that it should work. Still can you please elaborate on this idea as I do not know how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you will need to stub-out (or mock-up) the external routines called by the best-fit algorithm code so that best-fit code can be dropped into a test program. Then use some kind of C unit-test suite and C coverage tool to help ensure that you have carefully tested all branches and all states of the code. (Unfortunately, I have no suggestions for such tools at this time.)